# In XPath, how do i look for something between two elements?

Tags: selenium, dom, xpath, xpath-2.0, xpath-1.0

**Problem:**
I am using Selenium to type data into input fields on this website.
One of the tables has a problem, as it doesn't have a unique id for these fields.
I want to type text into the input field under "project2", on "name2". All the projects has the same names inside their projects. The names might change, and they might add some new fields in the future.

**Question:**
Is it possible to make a XPATH query where i am doing something after project2 but at the same time before project3?
Example something like: `//something/preceding-sibling::tr and //something_else/following-sibling::tr`

*Thanks in advance.*

**Example code:**

```
<table border="0">
    <tr><td>project1</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name1</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name2</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name3</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name4</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>project2</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name1</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name2</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name3</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name4</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>project3</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name1</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name2</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name3</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>name4</td><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you what you want:

```
//tr[preceding-sibling::tr[td[.="project2"]]][not(preceding-sibling::tr[td[.="project3"]])][td[.="name2"]]/td/input
```

The above will find all `<tr>` elements that:

1. come after a `<tr>` element that contains a `<td>` with the text "project2" -> `[preceding-sibling::tr[td[.="project2"]]]`
2. come before a `<tr>` element that contains a `<td>` with the text "project3" -> `[not(preceding-sibling::tr[td[.="project3"]])]`
3. with a `<td>` element that has the text "name2" -> `[td[.="name2"]]`

It will then drill down to the `<input>` element inside a `<td>` element in that row.

Comment: `project 3` is `hardcoded`, what would happen if they add `project4` or `project5`  or even change the project 3  name to something else?

Comment: If product 4 comes after project 3, nothing will happen.  This is searching for a row between the rows named project 2 and project 3.  If project 4 was added between project 2 and project 3 it would no longer resolve to a single element, but based on the way the markup is currently laid out that would be strange and unusual behaviour.  If (in this scenario) you were checking how many input fields were returned using the XPath I supplied you would get a quick and clear indication that this new markup was strange/wrong.

Comment: Also it's probably worth pointing out that if project 4 was placed between project 2 and project 3, you would still get the intended element if you are using a basic `.findElement()` call because it will pick up the first node it finds.  If project 4 was placed before project 2 it would be ignored because it's not between project 2 and project 3.

Comment: if the name of project 3 was changed to something else you would get all input fields after project 2, but again if you are using a basic `.findElement()` call it will pick up the first node it finds.

Comment: All of this really is moot though, if the markup substantially changes most complex XPath's will break, that's why people suggest adding ID's to elements to make them easy to find and prevent the need to use XPath's based on markup structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below xpath :

```
//td[text()='project2']/../following-sibling::tr[2]/descendant::input
```

**Update :**

If `td[2]` is the problem then probably use this :

```
//td[text()='project2']/../following-sibling::*/td[text()='name2']/following-sibling::td/input
```

or even the below one :

```
(//*[text()='project2']/../following-sibling::*/*[text()='name2'])[1]/following-sibling::td/input
```

Comment: yes, this will probably work, but the problem is if they add another field in between, right? But this is a good candidate if its not possible in another way.

Comment: See above, bit modified. The last one is not recommended but last one would work even if they add few more `tr` or `td`

Comment: I would recommend to use this `//td[text()='project2']/../following-sibling::*/td[text()='name2']/following-sibling::td/input` since even it has multiple matching nodes, `Selenium` `find_element` will always pick the first one